# iOS webkit object session cookie not set with AJAX

Tags: php, ios, ajax, xcode

I am doing an app in Xcode (SWIFT 4.0) for iOS loading a local html file in UIKit WebKit with an AJAX request.

Xcode:

```
import UIKit
import WebKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

@IBOutlet weak var mWeb: WKWebView!

override func viewDidLoad() {
super.viewDidLoad()

// load page        
let htmlPath = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "navigator", ofType: "html")
let url = URL(fileURLWithPath: htmlPath!)
let request = URLRequest(url: url)
mWeb.load(request)  
}
```

The AJAX call:

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.withCredentials = true;
xhr.onreadystatechange = _CB;                                               
xhr.open("GET", "https://nav.example.com/CORS.php?sid=" + Math.random(), true);             
xhr.send();
```

The PHP script includes the following headers:

```
session_start();

header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: ' . $_SERVER['HTTP_ORIGIN'] ?: '*');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true');
```

However, the session cookie is not exchanged from the server to the client and back, i.e. the session is lost.

What do I do wrong?

Comment: Where is [`session_start()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-start.php)?

Comment: There is also a session_start(). Just added above.

Comment: Have you first confirmed that sessions and session cookies work without issue with a normal web browser?

Comment: Yes, it works fine in normal browsers like Safari. It also works on Android. Only problem is iOS and Xcode.

Comment: The header must be: header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: ' . $_SERVER['HTTP_ORIGIN'] ?: '*'); But it doesnt solve the problem.

Comment: @HenrikJuul-Nyholm Did you resolve it?